# How to DataTable to JSON in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, json, datatable

I have my three dataTable and I want to get them into a single JSON array.

I want to do sample json.
I have my three dataTable and I want to get them into a single JSON array.

I want to do sample json

```
DataTable dt1=new DataTable("Table1")

DataTable dt2=new DataTable("Table2")

DataTable dt3=new DataTable("Table3")

var data = {
        "DataTableName1":
            [
                {
                    "Name": "Cemal",
                    "Surname": "Kaya",
                    "Age": "30"
                },
                {
                    "Name": "Ali",
                    "Surname": "Yaman",
                    "Age": "10"
                }
            ],
        "DataTableName2":
            [
                {
                    "Marka": "Opel",
                    "Model": "1998"
                },
                {
                    "Marka": "renault",
                    "Model": "2015"
                }
            ],
        "DataTableName3":
            [
                {
                    "Marka": "Opel",
                    "Model": "1998"
                },
                {
                    "Marka": "renault",
                    "Model": "2015"
                }
            ]

    };
```

**-:Updated:-**

As @Izzy given answer, but still I have a problem. I want to use the data in DataTable

```
 SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("myTable",con);
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 adp.Fill(dt);

DataTableName1 = new List<DataTableName1>
    {
        new DataTableName1
        {
            Name = dt.Rows[i]["Name"],
            Surname = dt.Rows[i]["Surname"],
            Age = dt.Rows[i]["Age"]
        }
    }
```

Help me please I'm about to go crazy

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21727144/convert-dataset-with-multiple-datatables-to-json

Comment: @Baha, I replace your answer with editing your question. You can'not give problem or thoughs as a answer. You just again edit your question and update it. I recommend you that delete your answer as already append above.

Answer (score 0):

Using your `JSON` sample I used [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) to generate the relevant classes.

```
public class DataTableName1
{
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Surname { get; set; }
public string Age { get; set; }
}

public class DataTableName2
{
public string Marka { get; set; }
public string Model { get; set; }
}

public class DataTableName3
{
public string Marka { get; set; }
public string Model { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
public List<DataTableName1> DataTableName1 { get; set; }
public List<DataTableName2> DataTableName2 { get; set; }
public List<DataTableName3> DataTableName3 { get; set; }
}
```

Then I made use of [WebMethod Attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) so I can call the function using `ajax`.

The backend C# code looks like:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string Test()
{
    var root = new RootObject
    {
        DataTableName1 = new List<DataTableName1>
        {
            new DataTableName1
            {
                Name = "Cemal",
                Surname = "Kaya",
                Age = "30"
            }
        },
        DataTableName2 = new List<DataTableName2>
        {
            new DataTableName2
            {
                Marka = "Opel",
                Model = "1998"
            }
        },
        DataTableName3 = new List<DataTableName3>
        {
            new DataTableName3
            {
                Marka = "Opel",
                Model = "1998"
            }
        }
    };
    var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var strJson = js.Serialize(root);
    return strJson;
}
```

Using [JavaScriptSerializer Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) we can `Serialize` our root object so it returns in a `JSON` format.

Finally make the `ajax` call to our backend function.

```
<script>
    var dataFromAjax;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Test.aspx/Test",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                dataFromAjax = JSON.parse(data.d);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The final result looks like this.

```
{
"DataTableName1": [
    {
        "Name": "Cemal",
        "Surname": "Kaya",
        "Age": "30"
    }
],
"DataTableName2": [
    {
        "Marka": "Opel",
        "Model": "1998"
    }
],
"DataTableName3": [
    {
        "Marka": "Opel",
        "Model": "1998"
    }
]}
```

Comment: You're welcome, if the solution helps you please accept so others can benefit too

Comment: I need help. I wrote :(